# How do I convert the data from columns to rows using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++, I want to convert this matrix,

A 1 1 2 2 1
B 2 2 2 1 1
C 1 2 1 2 2
D 2 1 1 1 2

to this format (transpose from rows to columns);

A B C D
1 2 1 2
1 2 2 1
2 2 1 1
2 1 2 1
1 1 2 2

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What have you found when searching about how to do this? Please [**edit** your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1329581/edit) to add this information. Thanks :)

Comment: Write a script.

Comment: @Toto How to write a script? I'm new with notepad++, please advise!

Comment: I'd say write a script in your favorite scripting language. This is not a job for Notepad++.

Comment: Do you think you can use Excel instead? You know, right tool for the job...